# How to programmatically retrieve Cognos Report Metadata 11.1.7 using the Java SDK

Tags: java, command-line, sdk, report, cognos

I wish to connect to a Cognos server list all report ids in a package and programmatically retrieve their report metadata like title, description, and pathref using the Java SDK finding this report metadata by report id.

I am writing a command line utility that will output to a CSV file. There does not seem to be any documentation about this that I can find.  I am using Cognos Analytics version 11.1.7 with the Cognos Java SDK.

Comment: "in a package"?  What does that mean.  A package can behave like a folder.  Do you mean reports in a package-folder, or reports that use a package as a data source?

Comment: And keep in mind that reports in that folder don't necessarily use that package.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for but the Windows Cognos Analytics installs come with a CMTools utility which has a CMBrowser and a CMTools perspective.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-use-cognos-analytics-11-cmtools-cmbrowser-confirm-report-running-full-interactivity

Worth a look anyway

Comment: Thanks Daniel,, do you know if Cognos provides source code to cmbrowser?  I know that Cognos provides some examples in java.  Do you know if IBM provides any examples similar to cmbrowser that has java source code available?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry just saw this now.  I am not aware of the source code for that being available unfortunately.